# Determine whether bullet point has multilevel list and find string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the word document which contain bullet point and multilevel list against bullet point. I am looking to perform following steps through vba. Please assist on following code.

Steps:

1. Loop through each bullet point
2. Search string Supply Place and Payment notification and Notification Address
3. If bullet point have multi list (as 3rd point mentioned below) search amount, if amount found show msgbox

Sample Word Document text

• Supply Place notification Address 1

• Payment notification Address 2

• Payment notification Address 3:

(i) Place of Payment: India

(ii) Payment amount INR 10,000,000 only,

• Notification Address 4

(i) Place of Payment: USA

```
Sub Findbullet()
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
    With Selection
        For Each oPara In .Paragraphs            'Select each bullet point from selection
            If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then
                'DoEvents
                MsgBox oPara.Range
                'Search string Supply Place and Payment notification and Notification Address
                With oPara.Range
                    If Selection.Text = "Supply Place" Then MsgBox "Supply Place" 'doEvent
                    If Selection.Text = "Payment notification" Then MsgBox "Payment notification" 'doEvent
                    If Selection.Text = "Notification Address " Then MsgBox "Notification Address" 'doEvent
                End With
                'If bullet point have multi list (as 3rd point mentioned below) search amount, if amount found show msgbox
                With oPara.Find
                    .Text = "INR[0-9]{1,}"
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Forward = True
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                End With
                If oPara.Range.Find.Found Then
                    MsgBox ("Amount Found")
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Amount not Found")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Please note this question has posed on following forums.
https://ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1228360-determine-whether-bullet-point-has-multilevel-list-and-find-string
https://excelforum.com/word-formatting-and-general/1329890-determine-whether-bullet-point-has-multilevel-list-and-find-string.html
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29079289-9ce8-4869-aaed-5c13585064ab/determine-whether-bullet-point-has-multilevel-list-and-find-string?forum=worddev

Comment: And what isn't working with your code? What is happening? Are there any error messages? If so, what and where?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.excelforum.com/word-formatting-and-general/1329890-determine-whether-bullet-point-has-multilevel-list-and-find-string.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184.